# Can I tell Excel VBA to search for a sentence in my code?

Tags: excel, vba

I made a mistake with my code, and instead of `.FormulaR1C1 = ""` I wrote `.Value = 0`. 
I wrote the mistake a lot in the code, and I want to fix it.
is there a way to tell excel that wherever he finds the combination `.value = 0` to change it to `.FormulaR1C1 = ""`?
end if there isn't, is there a way to search the combination `.value = 0`, so I could manually change it?

Comment: Press ctrl+F find and replace

Comment: Just like on the worksheet, hit Ctrl & h for find replace. In your case you should be able to find `.Value = 0` and replace with `=""`. You are not entering a formula, just setting a cells value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yoni, as they said above, you're eseentially replacing **0** with an empty string...

```
Sub AdjustZeroCells()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim cell As Range

'sets worksheet variable
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

'only loops through cells with formulas
For Each cell In ws.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas)
    If cell.Value = 0 Then: cell.Value = ""
Next cell

'cleanup
Set cell = Nothing: Set ws = Nothing

End Sub
```

Danny,
[ExcelVBADude](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC5Z93LJulIuAICkZMSmcbGA?view_as=subscriber)

Comment: So if the value is an empty string the formule is an empty string as well?

Comment: Not exactly, but reads the same on the Sheet. `=""` appears the same as `""`. You could do `cell.Formula = "="""""`, but would output the same regardless. The Formula bar would read `=""` but the cell text would be empty.